# Error:org.fusesource.jansi.Ansi PluginClassLoader[org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle, 162.2228.14]

Tags: android-studio-2.3

[enter image description here][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2ptX.jpg     this is link of image

Comment: Welcome to SO, you might need to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [asking a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your code should be provided as text and not image (especially not photo of screen which is unreadible), so we can reproduce your problem. Plus you should give more details on what you're trying to do and what's your problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** I found a solution by luck. After deleting the folder `.AndroidStudio2.3` under `C:\Users\<your_user>` I could open the projects in Andorid Studio 2.3 normal again. Deleting this folder will also delate all your custom settings for Android Studio, so be sure to back up them if you want to keep them.

Still, I would recomend to switch to the new Android Studio:

I had this problem with multiple projects with the version 2.3 of Android Studio. Since I was already using [Android Studio 3.0](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/index.html) for some of my projects, I migrated the other projects also to the new version. With the new Android Studio and Gradle version it works normal again.

Answer (score 0):

open Gradle task, delete VM options.

Comment: Answer needs to be a little bit more detailed.